# Using Thunderbird 6 with Tor?

Tags: thunderbird, tor

Can anyone explain how to use Thunderbird 6 with the Tor network?

Right now, I have Vidalia setup on my Mac OS X 10.6.8 machine, and can browse the web via Tor with the Tor Button addon in Firefox 6. Is there an equivalent to Tor Button in Thunderbird 6+ so that I can toggle Tor on/off at will?

Finally, since I also have Linux machines, a platform independent solution is preferred...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FoxyProxy for switching proxy servers. Just configure it to use a SOCKS5 proxy at `127.0.0.1` port 9050.